# If $\lambda*I - A$ ill-conditioned, then is $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

I am trying to show the following logic:

if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $||(\lambda I-A)^{-1}||_2$ is $||(\lambda I-A)^{-1}||_2  >  \frac{1}{\eta}$ where $\eta$ is machine precision, then 
$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\delta A$ for some $||\delta A ||_2 \le \eta$.

So I tried to show it like this:

For some real number $\lambda$, I know from the problem statmeent that the quantity $||(\lambda I-A)^{-1}||_2$ is $||(\lambda I-A)^{-1}||_2  >  \frac{1}{\eta}$ where $\eta$ is machine precision. The condition number of $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ is $k((\lambda I-A)^{-1}) = ||((\lambda I-A)^{-1})||*||(\lambda I-A)||$.  Then, the condition number must be extremely high $k((\lambda I-A)^{-1}) = \infty $.  Therefore $(\lambda I-A)^{-1})$ must be singular.  And if $(\lambda I-A)^{-1})$ is singular, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Now, I am getting stuck working the $||\delta A ||$ in there.  How do I work that in there?  and, is my logic correct thus far?